# Java Spring - Thymeleaf return null object to controller

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, thymeleaf

I have a page which contain information about calculator results in database. When I try click a button to the next page if I would check more details then java catch exception:

```
The given id must not be null!; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The given id must not be null!
```

Why do I have this bug ?

My controllers:

```
@GetMapping("/form")  
    public String selectData(Model model){  
        model.addAttribute("calcResults", calculatorRepository.findAll());
        return "user/form";  
    }
```

-

```
@PostMapping("/show")
public String showDetails(@ModelAttribute(value = "calcResults") CalculatorResult calcResults,Model model){
    System.out.println(calcResults.getId());
    model.addAttribute("calcResults", calculatorRepository.findOne(calcResults.getId()));
    return "user/show";
}
```

-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css"/>
        <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  ></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/printThis/1.12.3/printThis.js"></script>

        <title>Result</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{css/bootstrap.min.css}" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
            <form action="#" th:action="@{/show}" th:object="${calcResults}" method="post">
            <div class="col-md-4">
        <h1>Historia</h1>
            </div>

            <div style="padding:0 20px"/>

                <table class="table table-striped">
                        <tr>
                            <th>ID</th>
                            <th>Data Wyjazdu</th>
                            <th>Data Przyjazdu</th>
                            <th>Akcja</th>
                        </tr>  
                <tr th:each = "calc : ${calcResults}">
                        <td th:text="${calc.id}"></td>
                        <td th:text="${#dates.format(calc.dataWyjazdu, 'dd-MM-yyyy')}"></td>
                        <td th:text="${#dates.format(calc.dataPrzyjazdu, 'dd-MM-yyyy')}"></td>

                        <td>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-xs">Przelicz</button>
                            <!--<a th:href="@{/sucess}" class="btn btn-success btn-xs">Szczegóły</a>-->
                        </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your binding isn't correct. You are missing two things:

1. Use the th:field attribute instead of the th:text attribute. That's why id isn't bind to the corresponding object.
2. It looks like the object binds to "calcResults" is a list of objects. I never made it work that way. I think dynamic binding doesn't work in general. Workaround: Create a wrapper class CalcResult which has an array-property, e.g. called items (replacing your list) ... + the following code:

   ```
   <tr th:each="calc, stat : *{items}">
     <input type="text"
        th:field="*{items[__${stat.index}__].id}">
     /* other fields of the objects stored in the array has to be insert here like in the line above */
   </tr>
   ```